# Ошибка при подключении gduplus.h

Tags: c++, include, gdi+

При подключении gdi+ выводит  кучу ошибок(>100)
вот первые из них:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplus.h(18): error C2226: синтаксическая ошибка: непредвиденный тип "IDirectDrawSurface7"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(28): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "GraphicsState"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(28): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(28): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(529): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "ObjectTypeIsValid"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(529): error C2433: BOOL: "inline" не разрешается для объявлений данных
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(529): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(532): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(555): error C2065: META_SETBKCOLOR: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(555): error C2056: недопустимое выражение
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(556): error C2065: META_SETBKMODE: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(556): error C2056: недопустимое выражение
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(557): error C2065: META_SETMAPMODE: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(557): error C2056: недопустимое выражение
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(558): error C2065: META_SETROP2: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(558): error C2056: недопустимое выражение
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(559): error C2065: META_SETRELABS: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gdiplusenums.h(559): error C2056: недопустимое выражение
```

вот начало кода:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <GL/glut.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <stdafx.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <gdiplus.h>
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    #pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
```

**Теперь вот такие ошибки:**

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\excpt.h(120): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: }
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\excpt.h(120): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "}"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\excpt.h(120): error C2059: синтаксическая ошибка: }
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h(35): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winuser.h(35): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(285): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "ptPosition"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(285): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(285): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(286): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "ptSize"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(286): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(286): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(287): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "wStyle"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(287): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(287): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(288): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "wPattern"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(288): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(288): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(411): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "DataBytes"
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(411): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(411): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\wingdi.h(412): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "InjectionPoint"
```

Comment: да, с mingw всё компилируется отлично, но не запускаются .exe. Можете написать как надо скомпилировать файл main.cpp находящийся тут c:/MinGW. Может ошибка в том как я компилирую

Comment: В консоли:

    g++ -o main main.cpp
    ./main

Запустится main.exe

Comment: User@User-ПК /mingw
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf7): undefined ref
erence to `CreateStreamOnHGlobal@12'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d0): undefined re
ference to `GdiplusStartup@12'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1f7): undefined re
ference to `GdiplusShutdown@4'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus11Gdiplus
BasenwEj[Gdiplus::GdiplusBase::operator new(unsigned int)]+0xd): undefined refer
ence to `GdipAlloc@4'

Comment: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus11Gdiplus
BasedlEPv[Gdiplus::GdiplusBase::operator delete(void*)]+0xd): undefined referenc
e to `GdipFree@4'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus5ImageD2E
v[Gdiplus::Image::~Image()]+0x19): undefined reference to `GdipDisposeImage@4'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus5ImageD1E
v[Gdiplus::Image::~Image()]+0x19): undefined reference to `GdipDisposeImage@4'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text

Comment: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7Gdiplus5Image5C
loneEv[Gdiplus::Image::Clone() const]+0x1f): undefined reference to `GdipCloneIm
age@8'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7Gdiplus5Image5C
loneEv[Gdiplus::Image::Clone() const]+0x77): undefined reference to `GdipDispose
Image@4'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7Gdiplus6Bitmap5
CloneEv[Gdiplus::Bitmap::Clone() const]+0x20): undefined reference to `GdipClone
Image@8'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7Gdiplus6Bitmap5

Comment: CloneEv[Gdiplus::Bitmap::Clone() const]+0x7a): undefined reference to `GdipDispo
seImage@4'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus6BitmapC1
EP7IStreami[Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap(IStream*, int)]+0x46): undefined reference t
o `GdipCreateBitmapFromStreamICM@8'
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbbdMOD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus6BitmapC1
EP7IStreami[Gdiplus::Bitmap::Bitmap(IStream*, int)]+0x65): undefined reference t
o `GdipCreateBitmapFromStream@8'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: вот такие ошибки =(

Comment: код взял отсюда 
http://hashcode.ru/questions/30058/как-загрузить-png-изображения-через-gdi

Comment: @xPlayerAdv Обновил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

#### Информация по сборке с помощью `mingw-gcc`

---

Вообще говоря, переходить на `MinGW` только из-за того, что не получилось в сделать что-то в `Visual Studio` - это не очень дальновидно, и я бы на вашем месте разобрался бы как сделать это в студии *(работа с `IDE` все-таки проще, нежели работа напрямую в консоли).*

Тем более, вы лишаетесь классной возможности жмякнуть на кнопку `Build` и получить на выходе готовых `exe`-файл без возни с консольными командами.

---

Но раз уж вы выбрали этот непростой путь, то ход ваших действий должен быть примерно следующим:

- Ошибки типа `unresolved reference` появляются из-за того, что ваша программа ссылается на некоторые объявления функций `libgdiplus`, однако самих реализаций этих функций не находит, т.е *проще говоря, не подключается соответствующая библиотека.*
- Для того, чтобы из библиотеки `gdiplus.dll` сделать соответствующую библиотеку импорта для `MinGW`, необходимо запустить утилиту `MinGW` под названием `reimp`.
- Саму библиотеку `gdiplus.dll` можно найти в `/Windows/WinSxS/...`

---

**Если подытожить, то сборка в вашем случае будет выполняться так:**

```
reimp gdiplus.dll
gcc -IincXXX -LlibYYY main.cc -lstdc++ -lgdiplus -mwindows
// Вместо gcc можно использовать g++ без флага -lstdc++
```

---

- **`incXXX`, `libYYY`** - это ваши пути для необходимых заголовочных файлов и библиотек соответственно.
- Результат работы `reimp` должен быть доступен по пути **`libYYY`** или просто находиться в одном месте с файлом **`main.cc`**

Comment: теперь другие ошибки

Comment: Попробуйте создать пустую программу с одной строчкой `#include <winuser.h>` и посмотрите, будут ли ошибки. Если нет - то проблема, вероятно, в порядке инклюдов в вашей программе. Если ошибки те же самые, то могу предположить, что у вас неверные настройки компилятора.

Comment: можно по подробней про настройки?

Comment: сново ошибки

Comment: reimp не выполняется
reimp: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте #include <windows.h> сделать первым.

Comment: ошибка такая же как в случае когда я подключил <ddraw.h> перед <gdiplus.h>

Comment: Возьмите пустой файл и **по одному, начиная с <windows.h>** добавляйте .h

Когда полезут ошибки отпишите (только конкретно со всеми данными)

Comment: вот на windows и лезут, причём те же

Comment: не могу отправить все ошибки

Comment: Фантастика. Я только что проверил:

    #include <windows.h>
    /*
    #include <iostream>
    ....
    */

    g++ t.cpp
    /mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Ну, это не ошибка (т.к. в файле нет main()).
Что у Вас за компилятор ?

Comment: vc++ 2010, я думаю ошибка в настройке компилятора
цитата:
могу предположить, что у вас неверные настройки компилятора.
(2 дня назад)Котик_хочет_кушать

Comment: @xPlayerAdv попробуйте сменить компилятор. MinGW просто скачиваете, раскрываете архив и прописываете PATH к ./bin